# Automatically highlight date inside CompactCalendarView from Firebase database

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, calendar

I am using CompactCalendarView for adding calendar to my events activity. With the code `Event ev1 = new Event(Color.BLUE, 1621468800000L);compactCalendar.addEvent(ev1);` i can add highlight below the date as it shown it screenshot below. It uses date in milliseconds converted to long to highlight date. I also added onDayClick class to open new activity after date is pressed.

[highlighted date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEVIo.jpg)

Now i'm using Google Firebase. And successfully added FireBaseAdapter to display database content. So, here is my question, how can i make CompactCalendarView to pick a "dateInMilliseconds" from my database and use it to highlight date.

```
public class Events extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Calendar";
    private CalendarView mCalendarView;
    CompactCalendarView compactCalendar;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MMMM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    RecyclerView eventsRecycler;
    EventsAdapter eventsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events);
        
        eventsRecycler = findViewById(R.id.eventsRecycler);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        eventsRecycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<EventsItem> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<EventsItem>().setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("events"), EventsItem.class).build();

        eventsAdapter = new EventsAdapter(options, this);
        eventsRecycler.setAdapter(eventsAdapter);

        compactCalendar = (CompactCalendarView) findViewById(R.id.compactcalendar_view);
        compactCalendar.setUseThreeLetterAbbreviation(true);
        compactCalendar.displayOtherMonthDays(true);
        compactCalendar.shouldDrawIndicatorsBelowSelectedDays(true);

        Event ev1 = new Event(Color.BLUE, 1621468800000L);
        compactCalendar.addEvent(ev1);
        Event ev2 = new Event(Color.BLUE, 1621900800000L);
        compactCalendar.addEvent(ev2);

        compactCalendar.setListener(new CompactCalendarView.CompactCalendarViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDayClick(Date dateClicked) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();

                if (dateClicked.toString().compareTo("Tue May 25 00:00:00 GMT+06:00 2021") == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Events.this, placeholder.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (dateClicked.toString().compareTo("Thu May 20 00:00:00 GMT+06:00 2021") == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Events.this, placeholder.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

If its not possible with CompactCalendarView, what else can i use to achieve my goal?